# Compare Function used by Qsort - Comparing (char **)

Tags: c, sorting

Here is the compare function:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char* *s = (char* *) a;
    char* *t = (char* *) b;
    return sort_order * strcmp(*s, *t); // sort_order is -1 or 1
}
```

Now my question is what is the reasoning behind **casting** to a `double pointer` of a particular type? Or rather, *why is the double pointer cast needed* and *how is it used internally*?

Other variables used:
`char **wordlist;` `int nbr_words;` (array elements are) `char *word;`

Ex qsort call: `qsort(wordlist, nbr_words, sizeof(char *), compare);`

Comment: Not an answer, but your code contains integer overflow possibility if `sort_order == -1` and `strcmp` returns `INT_MIN`.

Comment: In what case would `strcmp` return `INT_MIN` (which is also a macro for what value?)?

Comment: Your compare usage looks wrong, it should be a cast to (single)pointers to char and then strcmp them.

Comment: Well I don't know if it's wrong, because it's working. I just wanted to know the reasoning behind the cast to the double pointer :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice My point was, that the cast is not logical.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice, it can return any value `< 0` when `s1` is "smaller" than `s2`. `INT_MIN` is smallest possible `int`. On common architectures (2-complement) `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX - 1`.

Comment: @self: Casting to a `char *` would be completely wrong and undefined behaviour if the two arguments actually passed were `char **`, which they almost certainly are, here. You *must* cast back to the same type which was converted to `void *` in the first place. If `char **` was passed to `compare()`, you can't just cast it to `char *`, pass it to `strcmp()`, and hope it's going to work, because it won't.

Comment: @self this is also exhibited and explained in Paul Griffiths' answer :)

Comment: @self: `qsort()` will pass pointers to the elements to the `compare` function. If your elements are type `char *`, `qsort()` will pass `char **`. If it didn't work this way, you wouldn't be able to actually sort anything.

Comment: `wordlist` is defined as `char **`, and each element is a `char*`. That being said, Paul is right in saying that. In fact, the third argument, `sizeof(char*)` points that out further I think...

Comment: @self: I've added an edit to the bottom of my answer to explain what's going on, here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would help if you showed the definition of `wordlist`, but most likely it's defined as a `char **`. The `compare()` function receives a pointer to each element of your list. If each element of your list is of type `char *`, then `compare()` is going to receive two pointers to `char *`, or two `char **` in other words.

The conversion to `char **` (note that an actual *cast* would be superfluous, in this particular case, if you weren't going from a `const` void pointer, to a non-`const` `char **`) itself is necessary because `qsort()` has to work on any kind of type, so the arguments get converted to `void *` before they are passed. You can't deference a `void *` so you have to convert them back to their original types before doing anything with them.

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_int(void * a, void * b) {
    int * pa = a;
    int * pb = b;
    if ( *pa < *pb ) {
        return -1;
    } else if ( *pa > *pb ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int compare_double(void * a, void * b) {
    double * pa = a;
    double * pb = b;
    if ( *pa < *pb ) {
        return -1;
    } else if ( *pa > *pb ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int compare_any(void * a, void * b, int (*cfunc)(void *, void *)) {
    return cfunc(a, b);
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    if ( compare_any(&a, &b, compare_int) ) {
        puts("a and b are not equal");
    } else {
        puts("a and b are equal");
    }

    double c = 3.0, d = 3.0;
    if ( compare_any(&c, &d, compare_double) ) {
        puts("c and d are not equal");
    } else {
        puts("c and d are equal");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./comp
a and b are not equal
c and d are equal
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

The `compare_any()` function will compare any type which is supported, in this case, `int` and `double`, because we can pass a function pointer to it. However, the signature of the passed function must be the same, so we can't declare `compare_int()` to take two `int *` arguments, and `compare_double()` to take two `double *`. We have to declare them both as taking two `void *` arguments, and when we do this, we have to convert those `void *` arguments to something useful within those functions before we can work with them.

What's happening in your case is exactly the same, but the data themselves are pointers, so we're passing pointers to pointers, and so we need to convert `void *` to, in your case, `char **`.

EDIT: To explain some confusion in the comments to the original question about how `qsort()` works, here's the `qsort()` signature:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int(*compar)(const void*, const void*))
```

`base` is a pointer to the first element of an array, `nmemb` is the number of members of that array, and `size` is the size of each element.

When `qsort()` calls `compar` on, say, the first and second elements of your array, it'll send the address of the first element (i.e. `base` itself) and the address of the element (i.e. `base + size`).

If `base` was originally declared as an array of `int`, then the compare function must interpret those pointers it receives as pointers to `int`, as `int *`. If `base` was originally declared as an array of strings, as a `char **`, then the compare function must interpret those pointers as pointers to `char *`, i.e. as `char **`.

In all cases, the compare function gets pointers to elements. If you have an `int` array, then you must interpret those pointers as `int *` in your compare function. If you have a `char *` array, then you must interpret them as `char **`, and so on.

In this case, you obviously *could* call `strcmp()` if you just passed plain `char *` arguments to the compare function. But, because `qsort()` is generic it can only pass pointers to the compare function, it can't actually pass the value of your elements - it's the use of `void *` which allows it to be generic, because any type of object pointer can be converted to `void *`, but there is no equivalent datatype to which any *non-pointer* value can be converted. For that reason, it has to work the same way with regular types like `int` and `double`, with pointers, and with structs, and the only way to get it to work correctly with all possible types is to have it deal with pointers to elements, not with the elements themselves, even when the elements are themselves also pointers. For this reason, it might *seem* like you're getting an unnecessary level of indirection, here, but it actually *is* necessary in order for `qsort()` to be able to function in the generic way that it does.

You can see this more clearly if I modify the code above so that `compare_any()` is more similar to `qsort()`, and takes not two pointers, but a single pointer to a two-element array of various types (slightly contrived example, but we're keeping it simple):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_int(void * a, void * b) {
    int * pa = a;
    int * pb = b;
    if ( *pa < *pb ) {
        return -1;
    } else if ( *pa > *pb ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int compare_double(void * a, void * b) {
    double * pa = a;
    double * pb = b;
    if ( *pa < *pb ) {
        return -1;
    } else if ( *pa > *pb ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int compare_string(void * a, void * b) {
    char ** pa = a;
    char ** pb = b;
    return strcmp(*pa, *pb);
}

int compare_any(void * arr, size_t size, int (*cfunc)(void *, void *)) {
    char * first = arr;
    char * second = first + size;
    return cfunc(first, second);
}

int main(void) {
    int n[2] = {1, 2};
    if ( compare_any(n, sizeof(*n), compare_int) ) {
        puts("a and b are not equal");
    } else {
        puts("a and b are equal");
    }

    double d[2] = {3.0, 3.0};
    if ( compare_any(d, sizeof(*d), compare_double) ) {
        puts("c and d are not equal");
    } else {
        puts("c and d are equal");
    }

    char * s[] = {"abcd", "bcde"};
    if ( compare_any(s, sizeof(*s), compare_string) ) {
        puts("'abcd' and 'bcde' are not equal");
    } else {
        puts("'abcd' and 'bcde' are equal");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./comp
a and b are not equal
c and d are equal
'abcd' and 'bcde' are not equal
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

As you can see, there's no way `compare_any()` could accept both an array of `int`, and an array of `char *`, without the `compare_string()` function getting a pointer it needs to treat as a `char **`, because of the pointer arithmetic it performs on the array elements. Without that additional level of indirection, neither `compare_int()` nor `compare_double()` could function.

Comment: It looks to me like the values passed are elements to the array (surely). These are passed as pointers into the compare function. Since `qsort` takes *any* type, as you said, they're void pointers. So you have to cast them back to their original type, which makes sense. I guess I'm just confused as to why they aren't just cast back to `char *X` & `char *Y`, and then passed to `strcmp` as `strcmp(X, Y)`.

Comment: Well looking at your edit, that makes sense! Still new to pointers, and I guess it just seemed like an extra unecessary `*` cast, but considering that it's not just a piece of data and the data is in itself a pointer, the extra step is needed. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Because if your elements were `char *`, and `compare()` takes a pointer to an element, then you have to pass it a `char **`. `compare()` has to be consistent. If you were working with straight `double`s, you'd have to pass a `double *`, because you can't cast `double` to `void *`. For the same reason, although passing a `char *` would work in general, this function requires that you pass pointers to your elements, so you have to pass it a pointer to pointer to `char`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I must say I am pleasantly surprised; I was wrong, somehow I confused pointers to an array.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Note that in your question, the actual *cast* is not necessary - since we're dealing with `void *`, this: `char* *s = (char* *) a;` can (and, to my mind, should) be written `char ** s = a;` An actual cast is not necessary when converting to or from `void *`, it will implicitly convert. If you were trying to dereference it directly (i.e. without first storing it in `char ** s`) then you *would* need to cast, e.g. `strcmp( *((char **) a), *((char **) b) );`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths You have to cast if you have a const void*

Comment: @self.: Not if you're converting it to another object pointer which is also `const` qualified. You need a cast to convert any pointer to `const` type to a pointer to its equivalent non-`const` type, not just `void *`. You can convert a non-`const` object pointer to a `const void *` without a cast.

Comment: qsort has the last parameter a function pointer with const paramenters.

Comment: OK, I see where you're going, now. Yes, in the function in the original question, the cast is necessary since it's taking a `const void *` to a non-`const` `char **`.